# Unable to add a variable in Julia DataFrame

Tags: julia, julia-dataframe

I am trying to read all files from a folder and trying to create filename variable based on name of the file

I am using the below code to do it. But I am unable to add the variable which lets me know the filename -

```
using DataFrame
using Queryverse
using VegaLite
using Statistics
using CSV
using Glob

path = "D:\\Udemy\\FInancial_Engineering_Lazy_Programmer\\Yfinance_Data"
files = glob("*.csv", path)

df_com = DataFrame()
for file in files
    df = CSV.File(file)
    df[:filename] = first(split(last(split(file, "\\")),"."))
    append!(df_com, df)
end
```

I am getting the below error -

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: invalid index: :filename of type Symbol
Stacktrace:
 [1] to_index(i::Symbol)
   @ Base .\indices.jl:300
 [2] to_index(A::CSV.File{false}, i::Symbol)
   @ Base .\indices.jl:277
 [3] to_indices
   @ .\indices.jl:333 [inlined]
 [4] to_indices
   @ .\indices.jl:325 [inlined]
 [5] setindex!(A::CSV.File{false}, v::Tuple{SubString{String}, Vector{Symbol}}, I::Symbol)
   @ Base .\abstractarray.jl:1267
 [6] top-level scope
   @ .\REPL[161]:3
```

There is no problem in creating the filename, but there is a problem in adding it to dataframe. The below code works fine and provides the filename, but unable to add it as a variable

```
for file in files
    println(first(split(last(split(file, "\\")),".")))
end
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

This is the most terse way to do it:

```
reduce(vcat,
       CSV.read.(files, DataFrame),
       source=:filename => chop.(basename.(files), tail=4))
```

Now, let me add some comments on your code, I hope they will be helpful:

- `split(file, "\\")` is not recommended, as it would work only on Windows, it is better to use `basename` that will work on all operating systems;
- using `first(split(your_filename,"."))` is not correct, as it will produce a wrong result if your file name contains multiple `.` in it; it is cleaner to `chop` four last characters as you know they are `.csv`;
- `CSV.File(file)` does not produce a `DataFrame` object; that is why later `df[:filename] = first(split(last(split(file, "\\")),"."))` fails; better use `CSV.read(file, DataFrame)` to efficiently create a data frame, in which case you could e.g. add a column like this `df.filename` = first(split(last(split(file, "\")),"."))`
- having changed the code above your code would work, but then using `vcat` is more efficient than repeated call to `append!`, as `vcat` is optimized for merging multiple data frames, the `reduce(vcat, ...)` part makes sure that you can pass a vector of data frames (instead of having to list them);
- finally a benefit of `vcat` over `append!` is that you do not have to create the `:filename` column manually, as `vcat` supports `source` keyword argument to handle your use case.

I hope these hints help you in using DataFrames.jl in general.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I was trying to combine multiple codes from Stackoverflow to implement the Python code I know. I will try to check the details documents for the functions mentioned by you. Thanks again for the prompt reply :)